# How to store and retrieve date time in Windows Registry with REG_BINARY type in hex(FILETIME) format using vc++

Tags: file, datetime, visual-c++, registry, hex

Starting on Windows 8, all the enabled and disabled start-up application are being stored under registry path **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\ SOFTWARE\ Microsoft\ Windows\ CurrentVersion\ Explorer\ StartupApproved\** having date time stored under REG_BINARY data-type.

Disabled Item:
`<Application Name>       REG_BINARY           03 00 00 00 31 06 4b d7 ea 89 cf 01`

Enabled Item:
`<Application Name>       REG_BINARY           02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

those hex values denotes disabled date & time.

I want to know how to convert the retrieved hex values to date&time?

also

similarly how to convert the date&time to hex values and store?

Comment: There's more to it, the first 4 bytes encodes an otherwise unguessable int32 value.  The last 8 bytes are a FILETIME, convert with FileTimeToSystemTime().  Avoid poking at undocumented registry keys.

Comment: @HansPassant I managed to get those last 8 bytes and converted to date & time successfully, but I could not convert the filetime to byte/hex values to store back.

Comment: FILETIME is 8 bytes. Did you try to just store those bytes?

Comment: @manuell What I did is, retrieved the registry value in BYTE[12] and copied the last 8 bytes to the memory of FILETIME and used FileTimeToSystemTime to convert and output is perfect. What I need is, I have to store the time back to registry value. How will I do it?

Comment: I don't understand. Copy the 8 bytes of your new FILETIME at the end of the BYTE[12] and write it back to the Registry. What's your problem?

Comment: @manuell It writes some junk values. Have you tried to do so? If you have tried, then let me know was it working or aren't.

Comment: If you did try something, show us your code and why you think il fails.

Comment: `char chTempVal[8];`
`memcpy(chTempVal, &fileTime, sizeof(FILETIME));`

`bValue[0] = 0x03;`
`bValue[1] = 0x00;`
`bValue[2] = 0x00;`
`bValue[3] = 0x00;`
`for (int ni = 0 ; ni < 8 ; ni++)`
`{`
`memset(&bValue[ni+4], chTempVal[ni], 1);`
`}`

Comment: No need to an intermediate chTempVal[] No need either for 8 calls to memset, each one copying 1 bytes. A single call to memecpy from filetime to &bValue[ni+4] will do. But your problem is elsewhere. Update the question with code and value seen. Don't use comment for that.

Comment: @manuell Thanks dude! Solved it!! The problem was at RegSetValueEx(), Now it works good.